# How to create specific DataFrame based on other df in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have DataFrame like below:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"Country" : ["Brazil", "Brazil", "Germany", "Germany", "UK"],
                     "Order method" : ["Phone", "Retail", "Web", "Web", "Retail"]})
```

And I would like to create new DataFrame based on above data frame where I would like to see result as below:

[image]

Comment: Not the same as you intended output, but you might want to try `pd.crosstab(data["Country"], data["Order method"])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for add missing categories:

```
s = data.groupby(['Country','Order method']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
print (s)
Country  Order method
Brazil   Phone           1
         Retail          1
         Web             0
Germany  Phone           0
         Retail          0
         Web             2
UK       Phone           0
         Retail          1
         Web             0
dtype: int64
```

For `DataFrame` add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = (data.groupby(['Country','Order method'])
          .size()
          .unstack(fill_value=0)
          .stack()
          .reset_index(name='Count'))
print (df)

   Country Order method  Count
0   Brazil        Phone      1
1   Brazil       Retail      1
2   Brazil          Web      0
3  Germany        Phone      0
4  Germany       Retail      0
5  Germany          Web      2
6       UK        Phone      0
7       UK       Retail      1
8       UK          Web      0
```

Last if necessary replace duplicated values to empty strings use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].mask(df['Country'].duplicated(), '')
print (df)

   Country Order method  Count
0   Brazil        Phone      1
1                Retail      1
2                   Web      0
3  Germany        Phone      0
4                Retail      0
5                   Web      2
6       UK        Phone      0
7                Retail      1
8                   Web      0
```

Comment: thank you guys! And tell me please also, how can I filter for example how Order method are in Brazil ?